# Covariant derivative-Differential

Tags: differentiation, covariance

I was trying to prove that the derivative-four vector are covariant. This can be proved only if you consider the time and space derivatives to be

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial t^\prime} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial t^\prime}$

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1^\prime}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial x_1^\prime} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial x_1^\prime}$

I was trying to understand but I'm afraid I can't.. if oyou for instance add the terms in the second part of the equations you get

$\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\dfrac{\partial t}{\partial t^\prime} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x_1} \dfrac{\partial x_1}{\partial t^\prime}=\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime} + \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime} =2 \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime}\neq \dfrac{\partial}{\partial t^\prime}$

How is that possible?

Comment: Would http://math.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question? Basically the question (v2) is treating the [chain rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule) in an incorrect manner.

Comment: This is just the chain rule for partial derivatives. It is *not true* that $\partial/\partial t' = \partial t/\partial t' \partial/\partial t$. Just try it on some function that depends on both $x,t$ to see it break.

Comment: And it is written incorrectly. You should have the operators on the right, $\partial t/\partial t'\partial/\partial t\ldots$. Otherwise you will do unnecessary differentiations of $\partial t/\partial t'$ etc.

Answer (score 1):

As noticed by [Michael Brown](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/17320/michael-brown), your last equation is totally wrong.

For instance take : $$ t' = t - x_1 $$
$$x'_1 = t + x_1$$, so that $$t = \frac{(t' + x'_1)}{2} $$
So, you have $$\frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} = \frac{1}{2}$$

Consider the function $f(x_1, t) = (t - x_1) = t'$

Then $$ \frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x_1, t) =  \frac{1}{2} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} f(x_1, t) = \frac{1}{2}$$

But $$  \frac{\partial}{\partial t'} f(x_1, t) = \frac{\partial}{\partial t'}t' = 1$$

So $$ \frac{\partial t}{\partial t'} \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \neq \frac{\partial}{\partial t'}$$